# How to get the current nixos version (for example 23.05) in a nixos config?

Tags: nix, nixos

Is there a method to retrieve the current NixOS version within a Nixos configuration.nix? I'm in the process of upgrading from NixOS 20.03 to 23.05 and I'd like to maintain a single configuration that is compatible with both versions.

Due to some package versions being exclusive to either version, I require conditional logic, like an if or switch construct, based on the NixOS version to allow me to specify which version of a package to use in a given Nixos version/system.

I guess a workaround is to just run `nixos-version > /etc/nixos/nixos-version` and read this as a normal file. But if there is a way to do this natively in the config that would be ideal.

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or https://superuser.com/

Comment: @Rob Nix is a programming language, so this is similar to asking how to get the Python version from within a Python script.

Comment: Your question is about configuring nixos which is a Linux distro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [this pattern](https://gitlab.com/engmark/root/-/blob/6c705cdfe9c029da1db9144d53093cc7313cbc11/configuration.nix#L180-193):

```hs
{
  fonts =
    if (config.system.nixos.release == "23.05")
    then {
      fonts = [
        pkgs.nerdfonts
        pkgs.noto-fonts
      ];
    }
    else {
      packages = [
        pkgs.nerdfonts
        pkgs.noto-fonts
      ];
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty basic but does the job for me:

```
  nixosVersion = builtins.substring 0 5 ((import <nixos> {}).lib.version);
  phpVersionToUse =
    if nixosVersion == "23.05" then
      pkgs.php82
    else
      pkgs.php74;
```

Example via the cli:

```
$ nix-instantiate --eval --expr "builtins.substring 0 5 ((import <nixos> {}).lib.version)"
"22.05"
```